# Can I power my 5.7 V DC synth with a 9 V power bank?

Tags: voltage

I own a Roland JD-Xi synthesizer which is powered by an AC/DC adapter. The output voltage of the adapter is 5.7 V DC.

In an attempt to make things more mobile, some years back I made a cable that I could plugin into a 5 V power bank and my synth. It kind of worked but I got problems with some of the analog sounds on the unit, and most likely it is because of the missing volts, so to speak. I kind of ditched that project but now I have got to think about it again. One idea I have is to buy a 9 V power bank instead. I understand that some electronics support quite a wide range of volts.

So, I guess my question is: would it be unresonable to think that my synth actually could accept 9 V input although its power adapter outputs 5.7 V? If you think 9 V is too much/too high, could I make some little tweak to get it down a few volts?

If you are interested in the background, you can read about my project here:

http://muublog.blogspot.se/2016/01/making-jd-xi-mobile-by-replacing-ac.html

Thanks!

/Mathias

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 1):

9 volts is probably too high. What is the rated output current (Amps) of the original power supply? What is the rated current output of the 9v power bank? First, make sure that you have enough power output from the power bank for your synthesizer. After that, you want to get yourself a buck converter rated for the amount of power you're working with. Just search for "buck converter" on eBay and you should be able to find something adequate.

Comment: The current mentioned on both the synth and the power adapter is 1000 mA. Thanks for the search term hint :) Seems that something like this could help: https://www.ebay.com/itm/5A-DC-DC-Buck-Step-down-Converter-Voltage-Regulator-5V-36V-to-3-3V-6V-9V-12V-24V/322715090598?hash=item4b23517ea6:g:d0kAAOSwYlJW2k01

Comment: @Mathias Dahl Yeah that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a buck converter or voltage regulator to convert 9v to 5.7
https://www.amazon.in/Adraxx-LM2596-Converter-1-5-35V-Adjustable/dp/B01N23Z1JO/ref=pd_sbs_328_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=R6V2630TSPW8ZMB9A75Q